# How to Start PM2 Node JS with Babel and presets

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I'm having the following code in my package.json to start the script while developing:

```
....
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
      },
....
```

Now I want to deploy it to production. When I run `npm start` everything works fine. However, it will shut down when I close the terminal. So how can I use it with **PM2**?

This is what I've tried:

```
pm2 start src/index.js -x babel-node -p es2015,stage-2
```

Comment: can you try `--node-args`

Comment: @VipinKumar can you show the command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use `npm start` if you like:

`$ pm2 start npm -- start`

That said, for production deployment I would strongly recommend a) using a config file for your pm2 startup stuff (so you can bundle environment variables and such) and b) precompiling your assets as a build step rather than on startup.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)